# Precision of measuring $N$-fold period one time vs single period $N$ times

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, measurements

One quick (I was told, trivial) question. Is it more precise to measure $N$-fold period one time, or to measure a single period, $N$ times?

Ex. You could let the circular pendulum do 10 swings and report the time it took for those said swings, and then divide the time by the number of oscillations, or you could measure one oscillation $N$ times.
Common sense tells me that it's more precise to measure it $N$-fold and then divide the time.

Could anyone mathematically prove or disprove this statement? Or if it's already proven elsewhere, link it?
I would also be satisfied it someone could give hints on how to even prove it, so I can prove it myself (or disprove it) because I don't even know how to start such a proof beyond common sense.

Comment: Hint: how many experimenter's errors are introduced in each method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the uncertainty in a time measurement does not increase with the length of time being measured. (This is usually a good assumption in most modern experiments.) Let's also assume that in the $N$-period single measurement, we know exactly how many periods we're measuring (which is a good assumption as long as your uncertainty is much smaller than the period). Let's compare the total uncertainty on the two techniques' final result.

---

Suppose you make $N$ measurements of one period. Each measurement has an uncertainty $\sigma_t$. To obtain the final result, you take the average of the $N$ measurements (the sum divided by $N$). The uncertainty $\sigma_{t,sum}$ on the sum of $N$ quantities is the quadrature sum

$$\sigma_{t,sum} = \sqrt{(\sigma_t)^2 + (\sigma_t)^2 + ... + (\sigma_t)^2}=\sqrt{N(\sigma_t)^2}=\sqrt{N}\sigma_t$$

Since the average is the sum divided by $N$ (which is exact), the uncertainty in the average is also the uncertainty in the sum divided by $N$:

$$\sigma_{t,avg} = \frac{\sigma_t}{\sqrt{N}}$$

---

Now suppose you make a single measurement of $N$ periods. Because we assumed that the uncertainty in the time measurement does not increase with the length of time being measured, the uncertainty in this measurement is still at most $\sigma_t$. For this measurement, we find the period by dividing by $N$. Since $N$ is exact, the uncertainty in the period from this measurement is

$$\sigma_{t,single}=\frac{\sigma_t}{N}$$

---

So, assuming that our above assumptions hold, making a single measurement produces a more precise result, especially as $N$ grows large. However, if the above assumptions are broken, then this may not be true any longer. For example, if the uncertainty in the time measured grows with the length of time measured (for example, if you're reading from a screen that has a finite precision, and longer time intervals force it to be less precise in displaying the reading; alternatively, if your timing device's measurements begin to drift from accuracy over long measurements, which is common with, for example, wind-up clocks), then the single measurement might not be the most precise result. In addition, if your time uncertainty is too large compared to the period, then you might also introduce an uncertainty in the number of periods you measured, which will affect the comparison of techniques in a more complicated way.

Comment: Thanks a lot. A precise and well structured explanation. Kudos.